# Segmentation fault after main exits when running gtests with my code as a shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, googletest

If I build my code as a static library and run my gtests, all is well. However, when I build my code as a shared library, the code runs fine when not run through gtest, but when I run the gtests the tests all pass, my output statement right before the end of main is printed, then I get a segmentation fault. It is unlikely that there is a real problem in my code because this is a big project that has hundreds of tests and they all segfault when run through gtest when built as a shared library.

I'm not sure how to provide a minimal working example of this since it likely has to do with system configuration, but can anyone suggest potential things that I can look for or reasons that this might happen?

Comment: What is the stack trace when it segfaults?

Comment: @Kurt Stutsman `Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f40f38536ad in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: Run in gdb.  When it segfaults find the line it faults on and print the value of the variables in that area of the code..

Comment: Check that the shared libs and the test executables are compiled with the same compiler version and using the same standard library.

Comment: stark: As I mentioned, it segfaults after main ends, and it is not in any of my code (seems like a linking-type problem). @Antonio Pérez They are. I did make some progress though - I am using the Protobuf library. I went back and rebuilt Protobuf as a shared library and then GTest works correctly on my code. Does that make sense to anyone? I had already built GTest with -fPIC because it was required to satisfy the linker.